# Midsegment of trapezoid

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a rectangular trapezoid $AB || CD$ $A \sphericalangle =D \sphericalangle =90^o$ $AC\perp CB$, $AD=\sqrt{15}$ cm. If $3AB=8CD$ then what does the midsegment equal to?

I know that the midsegment is $MN=\frac{AB+CD}{2}$, how to get the value of $AB$ or $DC$?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the information you provide is correct, then your diagram is very misleading. But anyways, let $AB=8x \Rightarrow CD=3x$. Then from the Pythagorean theorem

$$(AC)^2=(CD)^2+(AD)^2=9x^2+15$$

Construct a line segment from $C$ which intersects $AB$ at $P$ such that $PC\perp AB$. Then because $AB \parallel CD$ and $PC \parallel AD$, $AP=3x$ and $PB=5x$. Also note that by construction $PC=\sqrt{15}$. Applying the Pythagorean theorem to $\triangle BCP$ gives

$$(BC)^2=(PC)^2+(PB)^2=15+25x^2$$

Lastly you can apply the pythagorean theorem to $\triangle ABC$ which gives

\begin{align}
&(AB)^2=(AC)^2+(BC)^2 \\
\Rightarrow \;&(8x)^2=(9x^2+15)+(15+25x^2) \\
\end{align}

The rest is just a matter of solving for $x$, finding $AB$ and $CD$ and then using your formula to find the the length of the midline.

Answer (score -1):

Extend AD,BC to meet at P. Proportionality constant for AB, DC is $t$. In finding length of segments we use Pythagoras thm and proportion of similar triangles:

$$PD=u ~~,PC= \sqrt{u^2+9t^2} $$

$$ DA= \sqrt {15}$$

$$ (DC,AD)= (3t, 8t)$$

CB is computed and simplified $ CB^2= AB^2-AC^2 $

$$ CB= \sqrt {55 t^2-15} $$

$$ \frac{PD}{DC}=\frac{PA}{AB} $$

$$ \frac{PD}{PC}=\frac{PA}{PB} $$

Two equations two unknowns. Solving numerically

$$ {u = 1.341640786499874, t= 0.6277680455262371} $$

midsegment length

$$ MN = 5.5 t = 3.45372 ; $$

[image]